# Mapping over a list nested inside a dict

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

## Data

I'm curious if I can transform the following data

```
old_data = {
  "key0": [obj0, obj1],
  "key1": [obj2, obj3]
}
```

to

```
data = {
  "key0": [obj0.id, obj1.id],
  "key1": [obj2.id, obj3.id]
}
```

using dict comprehension.

So basically just replacing those list objects with a single attribute of the object itself. All the objects are from the same type and therefore have the `id` attribute for sure.

## Dict comprehension

I came up with the following solution which doesn't work:

```
data = {
  key: [obj.id]
  for key, obj_list in old_data.items()
  for obj in obj_list
}
```

#### Problem

The resulting dictionary just contains lists with exactly one value (the last value which was iterated) because of this line:

```
key: [obj.id]
```

creates every time just a new list with one value.

So I instead of creating a new list, I wanted to `append` new `obj_id`s to an existing list, but I don't know how.
I think it must look somehow like this:

```
key: data[key].append(obj.id)
```

But obviously this also can't work because `data` isn't assigned yet and even if it would be: the first `obj.id` couldn't be appended because the list was never initialized.

(I'm using Python 3.7)

Comment: What about `{key: map(operator.attrgetter('id'), obj) for key, obj in old_data.items()}` ?

Comment: @MatiasCicero didn't know about that possibility. Should also work, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## List comprehension

So I found a solution using list comprehension:

```
data = {
  key: [obj.id for obj in obj_list]
  for key, obj_list in old_data.items()      
}
```

Just had to move the loop (`for obj in obj_list`) inside the list comprehension.

This also solves the problem that for the first `obj` no list exists and further that no other `obj`s need the `append` method or something like this.

Answer (score 1):

### Functional approach

Here's a not so very pythonic, but still interesting way of doing it:

```
from functools import partial
from operator import attrgetter

old_data = {
  "key0": [obj0, obj1],
  "key1": [obj2, obj3]
}

data = dict(zip(old_data, map(list, map(partial(map, attrgetter('id')), old_data.values()))))
```